# Fetching a url from XML

Tags: javascript, xml, coldfusion

I am trying to fetch a url which is in tag in a xml file. I have to use this url in further part of the program. Can any body help ?

This code appear in a coldfusion file where I have to use the coldfusion variable on which I trying to set the url in FB sharing.

```
<script>

window.onload=function(){

    var r_data = ranger_descp(#rang_id#);
    <cfset rang_URL = r_data>
}

function loadXMLDoc()
{ 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","../rangers/js/rangers.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
    return xmlDoc;
}

var xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("../rangers/js/rangers.xml");
var object = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("site");
var url=new Array();
var id=new Array();

function ranger_descp(rang_id){
        //alert(xmlDoc);
        for(i=0; i< object.length; i++)
        {
            id[i]=object[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;      
            if(id[i] == rang_id)
            {          
                url[i]=object[i].getElementsByTagName("url")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                var r_url=url[i];
                return [r_url];        
            }            
     }
}
```

If anything is missing in it then please suggest :)

Comment: The XML itself would be useful.

Comment: Also, what about this doesn't work? All the functions are there to get a URL out of the XML (look at ranger_descp()).

Comment: Is `r_data` a javascript variable? Because CF runs on the server and knows nothing about javascript. So you cannot mix server and client side code this way: `<cfset rang_URL = r_data>`

Comment: Yes you are right Leigh :)
I have used it properly now...it's solved :)